# Apache jena fuseki installation in google compute engine

Tags: apache, google-compute-engine, fuseki

I am trying to install the apache jena fuseki in the google compute engine. All the installation process are done as per expectation but i cannot view the :3030 port in my browser it show me a blank screen.

is their any possible solution to install the Apache jena fuseki in the Google compute engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Go to my Console.

2) Choose you Project.

3) Choose "Compute Engine" instance.

4) Click "Networks" (It will say default).

5) Choose the interface for you Instances.

6) In firewall rule create a new rule with "Protocols & Ports"-"tcp:3030".

I hope this help you.